# How to extract JWT token from server response?

Tags: javascript, jwt, axios

I'd like to receive JWT token fron express back into my vue.js app using axios.

Here is what I came up with:

```
 handleSubmit: function () {
            axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/users/login", {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
          }).then( (res) => { 
                console.log('res is:', res); //JWT found here 
                console.log('token is:', res.headers.common['Authorization']); //<-Problem here

                this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
           })
            .catch( (error) => {
            this.showErrorLogin = true;
            if (error) {
             this.error  = error;
             }  
          });
```

After a scussessful post, I receive this in the console :

```
      res is: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}data: success: truetoken: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjViODZmOTE4YWNiMmI2Nzk3ZmEyYzFjNCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiamFzZW0iLCJpYXQiOjE1MzYxNTgyNTAsImV4cCI6MTUzNjE5NDI1MH0.Sgl8cTHTQxU8rvBWdr365SBKABnUdbeUNHYLflqXURM"__proto__: Objectheaders: {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object


token is: undefined
```

but I don't know how to extract it. I've also tried `res.headers['Authorization']` but get `undefined` instead.

Comment: can output , regarding this line: res with jwt token, im confused, if you received it, should be good, define extract ?

Comment: I added the response. The problem is how to extract the token from `res`.

Comment: that is the output from res object right?

Comment: That's right sir.

Comment: this line, "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjViODZmOTE4YWNiMmI2Nzk3ZmEyYzFjNCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiamFzZW0iLCJpYXQiOjE1MzYxNTgyNTAsImV4cCI6MTUzNjE5NDI1MH0.Sgl8cTHTQxU8rvBWdr365SBKABnUdbeUNHYLflqXURM" , try accessing the Bearer

Comment: The  very question is how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179483/discussion-between-remario-and-babr).

Comment: could you expand the headers field in the res object

Comment: `headers : content-type : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
__proto__ : Object
request : XMLHttpRequest
response : "{"success":true,"token":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjViODZmOTE4YWNiMmI2Nzk3ZmEyYzFjNCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiamFzZW0iLCJpYXQiOjE1MzYxNjA3NzIsImV4cCI6MTUzNjE5Njc3Mn0.YtKzE-RBMlYcuC8k34cs9ESnrDM0DGcoo_u-9EZjpj0"}"`

Answer (score 1):

The token can be passed in many ways

```
 // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['Authorization'] || req.headers['Bearer'];
```

Comment: Do not work. Please see the expanded header of the response in the comments above.

Comment: that output is not valid json, please copy exactly and format and repost in answer.